# Windows Azure - Microsoft.IdentityModel not found

Tags: dll, azure, appfabric

I installed WIF runtime and SDK on my machine. I added Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll to my azure web application and locally everything is running great. I build simple web application which use Azure AppFabric Access control. I follow azure labs for that and as I told, local everything is great. When I published my web application to Azure, I'm getting following error :

*Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.*

I get it after Appfabric Relaying part is going to return url, after sign in on identity provider. The weird thing is that I set **Copy Local to TRUE**, because that .dll is not part of Azure GAC. I tried to publish it again, but I received same error. I found few same problems on the internet but with no concrete solution. Does anybody here had something similar and probably have a working solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything that I need to deploy locally to Azure I make a copy of the DLL's in my project folder and reference them from there while setting copy local to true. Since doing this I no longer have any issues with DLL's not being published to Azure. I also do all of my building through the command line using MSBuild and publish the cspack by hand. This means that I do not rely on Visual Studio for doing the build or deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this and solution described in [this blog](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/eriko/archive/2011/01/14/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure.aspx.) helped. You will need to run this command from your role startup task:

```
gacutil /nologo /i .\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll
```

This startup task has to be run with full privilegies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling encryption on the creation of the deployment package and verifying that the dll is indeed present?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that (in short notes)? Thank you!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/04/16/digging-in-to-the-windows-azure-service-package.aspx <- in a nutshell, set/create an environment variable _CSPACK_FORCE_NOENCRYPT_ and set the value to true. Then rebuild the package

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment variable called: _CSPACK_FORCE_NOENCRYPT_ set the value to true.Restart your visual studio.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary as all this does is allow you to view the cspack file as it's not encrypted.